# How to build phpalanger phpc?

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio, phalanger

I've tried to build https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger, but after the build process it shows build errors. I tried VS 2015, maybe there it just a question of a wrong version?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue! For a reference see https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/issues/71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is outdated project, unload the Tests projects for now.

Comment: Yes, that works. I really didn't pay attention on that every error is related only for tests. Thank you Jakub!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the version of studio, see https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/blob/master/Solutions/Phalanger.sln it says Studio 14 which is VS 2015.

Would be worth checking the readme, see https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/tree/master/Source but this looks more like an issue in the code to me.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, and I thought the same, but I see there is no issue at github about that. Perhaps it works work some way for other people? :)

I thinking I should create issue on github, maybe developers could give some help on that build failure.